# Customer login is case sensitive

Tags: login, customer-account, ce-1.9.2.2

We have been having customers register with a capital letter in their email address. When they come back to login, they do not enter it capitalized and then cannot login.

How can we make it so that the email address is always submitted lowercase, or make it case insensitive during the login?

Answer (score 0):

Create an observer to listen for an event fired while creating the customer account, and run the email address through the [strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) function.

Also have an observer on the login checks (I'm sure there is an event you could listen to) and run the email through the `strtolower` function again. You should be golden!

If you don't want to use observers, you could look for a JavaScript-based solution...